# Dataframes not showing up in R Environment

Tags: r, rstudio

None of my data frames are showing up in my RStudio Global Environment. When I type `View(dataframe)` in the Console, they are displayed with their contents. But the Environment itself is blank -- it isn't showing any data frame that I was working with. I have attached a screenshot, illustrating my problem with the data frame named "ts1930_noerror."

How do I fix this?

[image]

As per a request in the comments, I'm including the code leading up to my issue. I'm not sure what caused the data frames to disappear, but this was my code:

```
duty_allyears_nodo_combined <- lapply(tsallyears_noerror_withdo_combined, function(df) {
         totrev <- round(df %>% summarise(totrev = sum(duty)/10^6) %>% pull(totrev), digits = 2)
         data.frame(year = names(years), totrev = totrev)
    })
```

I got these errors:

```
    Error in data.frame(year = names(years), totrev = totrev) : 
      arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
    Called from: data.frame(year = names(years), totrev = totrev)
    Browse[1]> 
    Browse[1]> years(1)
    Error during wrapup: could not find function "years"
    Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort and submit data to be used to reproduce your problem. While providing an image is helpful, it doesn't allow for reproducing the issue. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [mre] for details.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to post, because I don't know what caused the problem. But I have posted the code leading up to the issue. I hope that helps.

Comment: Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.